# How to add more blur hoverizr

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-effects

Hi can someone help me with adding more blur using Hoverizr.min.js

I have used the following code to blur an image, but I need to blur it more. The image size is around 1200px in height and 700px width.

The code  I am using is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('.box1').hoverizr({effect:'blur',speedOut:'slow'});
```

and the html is:

```
<img class="blur box1" src="img/img1.jpg" />
```

Any help how to add more blur would be great.

Comment: Anyone able to help with this? All  I want is to add more blur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after researching so many option with the blur, I decided to go old school.

How I did this was made the image blur in photoshop and place both images over each other with position absolute.

Once there was two images, one blur and the other under was focused. I just used the option fadein and fadeout with jquery. And it runs smoothly across all browsers.

Wish I was about to get this to work with hoverizr but sadly lack of content.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with CSS using [the filter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter). Browser support is [decent](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) but you will need a fallback version to support IE.

If your HTML contains this image:

```
<img class="blur box1" src="img/img1.jpg" />
```

You can add this in your CSS:

```
.blur {
    filter: blur(25px); /* can be an arbitrary amount */
}

.box1 {
    transition: filter 2s ease; /* give a transition */
}

.box1:hover {
    filter: none; /* remove the blur when you hover */
}
```

This is a simplified example; it only uses the standard filter syntax. In reality, you'll have to specify all of the vendor prefixes for maximum usability.

[**Here is a live demo of the effect.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cb3j9w1k/)

Edit: Check out [this useful blog](http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Cross-browser-Image-Blur-with-CSS) for useful tricks on maximizing the cross-browser compatibility and taking care of a few quirks of the filter.

Comment: Sorry to say but that does not work in firefox what was my major concern, So I would have to write a indpendent css for each.

Comment: it could work in firefox with an svg filter workaround (as outlined in the blog post i linked in my edit), but your solution is certainly more bullet-proof, although it uses double the resources. i just added this for posterity's sake, in case anyone else is looking for solutions. glad you solved your issue.

Comment: Exactly, I look forward to when webkits are implements fully cross all browsers.